# Why images overflow inline-block?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, inline

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="card">
        <span class="card-title">Album</span>
        <div class="card-content">
            <img class="album-thumbnail" src="a.jpg">
            <img class="album-thumbnail" src="b.jpg">
            <img class="album-thumbnail" src="c.jpg">
            <img class="album-thumbnail" src="d.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.card-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.album-thumbnail {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

In the browser I can see two columns of images, but the width of card-content ends where the first column ends. What causes this and how can I solve it?
This is how it looks currently:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cause you have a duplicate for `display` in this code section:

```
.card {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Remove this line `display: inline-block;` and it should work just fine. Here's a replica jsfiddle of the problem with the [applied solution](https://jsfiddle.net/L24rbfgn/)

Here's a screenshot with your element inspected: [image]

Another thing you should remove if you don't want space around the columns is `align-items: center;` inside the class `.card-content`.

Open the updated fiddle to see the changes.

Comment: I didn't notice, I had set display twice, but removing the last one, doesn't solve the problem, because I want that div's width to fit its content's width.

Comment: @AdriánSopár which div exactly? I've updated my question with a screenshot. Your card div does take the full width but it has padding of `24px`, if you want it to take the  full width, just remove the padding. Please be as specific as you can when asking a question

Comment: This is something, I want, but it doesn't look like this. I updated my question to let you see the problem.

Comment: @AdriánSopár have you opened the js fiddle I've provided for you inside my answer? It literally solves that problem...

Comment: I've opened, but that's not what I need. I don't want space around the columns.

Comment: @AdriánSopár updated the fiddle. Not wanting space around the columns is due to your div layout. Check the updated fiddle link.

Comment: I've opened the updated fiddle, but it's still not what I want, because I want to give a fix size for the width of album-thumbnail.